# Regex html tag data

Tags: html, regex

I'm getting (HTTP request) and I'm trying to get certain data out of it by using a regex, for example this part of the HTML:

```
<tr><th>Continent:</th><td class='trc'>Europe (EU)</td></tr>
```

How can I get the 'Europe (EU)' out of this?

I've tried this regex:

```
/<th>Continent:<\/th><td class='trc'>(.+)\s<\/td>/
```

But this does not work

Comment: You should not be using regexes to parse HTML. Use an HTML parser for that...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/139010

Comment: This is for a mIRC script but I figured that regexes are the same in mIRC scripting language as in PHP?

Comment: @plalx depending on the intent using a full blown SGML parser to extract a single bit of data is like attacking a rubber boat with naval artillery. There are plenty use cases for preferring to simple extract a few simple bits of data from HTML with regular expressions over a full blown parser. It's often even more resilient too since the regex method will survive minor changes in the source page structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are telling the regex to look for a space followed by `</td>`

```
/<th>Continent:<\/th><td class='trc'>(.+)\s<\/td>/  
                                         ^^
```

I'd recommend using `[^<>]+` to search for text between html tags.

```
/<th>Continent:<\/th><td class='trc'>([^<>]+)<\/td>/
```